Packet forwarding from dual stack interface to localhost
I have a linux SUSE host which has both ipv4 and v6 enabled, below are the interfaces:- eth0,app,eth1 however the default route is available for ipv4 via eth0. Kubernetes is running on this host(single node), and the cluster is in ipv6. I need help with some kind of mechanism to access my cluster from outside host, so will port forwarding my request from localhost:port to ipv6ClusterIP:port work?

The below ip table rules didnot work

sudo ip6tables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport <localhost_port> -j DNAT --to-destination [ipv6_addr]:<port>

I have tried socat , but that cannot be a permanent solution as reboot scenario should also  handled here.

By outside host do you mean your IPv4 host or a host behind your default gateway, ex. hosts from WAN?

In any case I think NAT in nftables or iptables works with either IPv4 or IPv6 addresses, I don't think you can do NAT from IPv4 to IPv6 because a packet carries both source and destination address, so you would have to change both which is not possible in a single rule or NAT chain.

@metablaster outside host can be either in ipv4 or ipv6

@metablaster you are right, couldnt change both

However with socket, I was able to achieve this

I was able to achieve this through socat,
socat TCP-LISTEN:<localhost_port>,reuseaddr,fork TCP6:[ipv6 cluster IP]:<port>

Just a concern, if we use this, as a daemon service, will there be any security concerns or impact ?
